# What is an incongruent primitive root?

Tags: number-theory

What's the formal definition of an incongruent primitive root?

I know the definition for primitive root is

$m^n\equiv k\pmod p$ where $\gcd(k,p)=1$.

Comment: Give more context. My best guess is you've seen this phrase in saying one primitive root is not congruent to another (e.g. "a set of incongruent roots") and misinterpreted it as being a property a single root can have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two primitive roots $a$ and $b$ are said to be incongruent primitive roots of $p$ if $a\not\equiv b (\text{mod}~ p)$.